# Maximizar tela sem borda sem esconder a barra de tarefas do Windows

Tags: winforms, vb.net

Quando eu coloco a janela para `FormBorderStyle = None` e maximizo-a, ela fica em tela cheia, ocultando a barra de tarefas.

Gostaria de saber como deixá-la maximizada, mas sem ocultar a barra de tarefas.

Comment: Não conheço de c#, mas no Delphi isso é resolvido deixando a propriedade Align, do Form, para AllClient. Não há a necessidade de nenhum POG,para isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a propriedade `FormBorderStyle` setada como `None`, você terá que tratar isso manualmente. Ou seja, se for usar **`WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized`**, a barra de tarefas **ficará atrás do form**.

Minha dica é você definir manualmente o tamanho do form, desconsiderando o tamanho da barra de tarefas (que é, por padrão, 40px desde o Windows 7). Obviamente o tamanho e localização da barra de tarefas pode mudar pelas configurações do usuário - existe a opção de usar "ícones pequenos" que diminui o tamanho da barra e também a opção de colocá-la em qualquer extremidade do monitor (cima, baixo, direita, esquerda). Isso sem contar que a barra de tarefas pode ser escondida automaticamente.

O código abaixo maximiza o form tomando como base a largura da tela e a altura da mesma (menos os 40px da barra de tarefas padrão).

Obviamente é possível obter as informações da barra da tarefa, como local e tamanho, mas pra isso seria necessário chamar alguma API do Windows. Dependendo da sua ideia, isso é muito trabalho pra um resultado não muito bom, talvez isso caiba noutra pergunta mais específica.

```
Private Sub BtMaximizar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width //Largura igual a largura da tela
    Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - 40 // Altura da tela, menos a barra

    Location = New Point() //New Point() cria um point com x = 0 e y = 0
    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
End Sub
```

Comment: Obrigado! :) <completando caracteres faltando>